# why innerHTML can't preserve the previous status (what should be used instead ?)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

It looks like `innerHTML` has (somehow) the same behavior as `document.write()`: both delete the previous html. I'm using an `id` for the same element (needed to show results) but with `innerHTML` , I just get the last result listed(last object) instead of getting them all listed. I tried `getElementsByClassName`but it didn't show anything.

```js
function drawTd (item) {
  outputHTML += '<td>' + item + '</td>';
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = outputHTML;
}

function drawSpecialTd (item) {
  outputHTML += item + '</br>';
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = outputHTML;
}

  
for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
  // array1 and array2 have each iteration 1 single value
  // but array3 may have more
  var outputHTML = '';
  outputHTML = '<table>';
  outputHTML += '<tr>';
  array1.forEach(drawTd);
  array2.forEach(drawTd);
  outputHTML += '<td>';
  array3.forEach(drawSpecialTd);
  outputHTML += '</td>';
  outputHTML += '</tr>';
  outputHTML = '</table>';
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" class="Classe"></div>
```

Comment: So you want to append text to the element? In that case, use the `+=` operator rather than `=`

Comment: Can you clearly explain what it is that you're tryin to accomplish and where you're running into an issue? Please include a [mcve] as well

Comment: @Rojo you mean : document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += outputHTML; ? but then can it handle repetition in different function?  thank you for the comment and I will try it now

Comment: The `br` element in HTML has a mandatory start tag and a forbidden end tag. `</br>` is nonsense.

Comment: @j08691 I have 2 arrays that inside a for loop they get only 1 result, however the 3rd array may have more (I'm working on an array of objects and need those arrays to split the object).. the problem is that my code works really fine with php, but switching to js I only get the last item inserted in array1 and array 2 (only the last iteration is shown) so it must be the innerHtml who is making a mess

Comment: ... yes, of course? That's literally the point of `innerHTML`, it _is_ an element's content as expressed as HTML markup. If you set a new value, you're literally setting an element's content. If you want to append/modify content instead, then _edit_ that value instead of assigning it. However, **far more importantly**: don't use innerHTML, use proper element management functions (createElement, append, remove, etc) instead of hacking the HTML markup instead. Using `innerHTML` trains you into thinking it's fine to use, an assumption that breaks the moment user generated content becomes involved

Comment: e.g: `function drawTd (item) { let td = document.createElement("td"); td.textContent = item; demo.append(td); }` and without any effort this is both cleaner, _and_ safer because even if `item` contains exploiting JS or the like, it'll never execute. (And you might be wondering "where is `document.getElementByid` for that `demo` element?" to which the answer is "you don't really need it: any elements with an id is globally exposed using that id as variable name. But if you do need it, cache that element _outside_ your function calls".)

Comment: Code does not make sense. You are calling the methods in the middle of creating a table, but you are not setting the rows to the table.... My guess is the real issue is you declare `var outputHTML = '';` inside of the loop.

Comment: I wouldn't use `innerHTML` in 2021 ... ever, but on top of that, I wouldn't put `<br>` outside `<td>`, if the special kind is even a td. Regardless, you accumulate on `outputHTML`, so once you have finished, that's the only time you use `innerHTML` ... but then again, I wouldn't use `innerHTML` **ever** in 2021.

Comment: What is the exact output you are looking for?

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi What's the issue with `innerHTML` in 2021? Is there a security consideraton, as suggested [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations)?

Comment: @terrymorse if your data contains special HTML entities it's able to break the layout + `innerHTML` is incapable of setting listeners + `innerHTML` trashes nodes every single time is used hence it's not RAM/CPU/GC friendly + with the pletora of libraries that do a better job at avoiding XSS attacks, sanitizing entities for content, allow adding listeners and avoid garbage per each update, all via template literals (see uhtml), there is no reason to use `innerHTML` if not by libraries that perfectly understand what are the issues in using `innerHTML`. Avoid `innerHTML` if you can.

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi thank you for your response, but I would like to ask you what would you use instead of innerHtml?

Comment: @YosraMH the same I'e suggested/used in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65807140/2800218 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue where you are resetting the outputHTML on every iteration of the loop. You need to move it outside so it is not being reset.

Creating helper methods to return strings would make more sense than altering the variables. A simple map() call with join() can make it easy to build up a list of tds in a string.

```js
function createTds(arr) {
  var cells = arr.map(function(text) {
    return "<td>" + text + "</td>";
  });
  return cells.join('');
}

function createSpecialTd(arr) {
  var cells = arr.map(function(text) {
    return text + "<br/>";
  });
  return "<td>" + cells.join('') + "</td>";
}

var arr1 = ["a1", "b1", "c1"];
var arr2 = ["a2", "b2", "c2"];
var arr3 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];


var table = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  table += "<table><tbody><tr>";
  table += createTds(arr1);
  table += createTds(arr2);
  table += createSpecialTd(arr3);
  table += "</tr></tbody></table>";
}
document.querySelector("#out").innerHTML = table;
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table { margin: 1em; }
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Using a string template literal can make it look a bit cleaner

```js
function createTds(arr) {
  var cells = arr.map(function(text) {
    return `<td>${text}</td>`;
  });
  return cells.join('');
}

function createSpecialTd(arr) {
  var cell = arr.map(function(text) {
    return `${text}<br/>`;
  }).join('');
  return `<td>${cell}</td>`;
}

var arr1 = ["a1", "b1", "c1"];
var arr2 = ["a2", "b2", "c2"];
var arr3 = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];


var table = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  table += `
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          ${createTds(arr1)}
          ${createTds(arr2)}
          ${createSpecialTd(arr3)}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `;
}
document.querySelector("#out").innerHTML = table;
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table { margin: 1em; }
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see whether the following is what you want to achieve (repetition operations on an element thru change in innerHTML):

```js
function repeat1()
{
var temp1=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=temp1+"-repeated";
}
```

```html
<input type=button onclick="javascript:repeat1();" value="Please click">
<div id=demo></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling this inside your functions:

```js
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = outputHTML;
```

overwrites the contents of the 'demo' element, erasing whatever was already there.

The fix: accumulate all markup in `outputHTML`, then save it once to the `demo` element.

```js
function drawTd (item) {
  outputHTML += '<td>' + item + '</td>';
}

function drawSpecialTd (item) {
  outputHTML += item + '<br>';
}

var outputHTML = '';

// this will create 10 separate tables:
for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
  // array1 and array2 have each iteration 1 single value
  // but array3 may have more
  outputHTML += '<table>';
  outputHTML += '<tr>';
  array1.forEach(drawTd);
  array2.forEach(drawTd);
  outputHTML += '<td>';
  array3.forEach(drawSpecialTd);
  outputHTML += '</td>';
  outputHTML += '</tr>';
  outputHTML += '</table>';
}

// store completed `outputHTML` to DOM 
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = outputHTML;
```