# How to display a list of element in as a list in HTML from a Javascript array from an API?

Tags: javascript, html, axios

My JS code is this but I want to be able to get the `moves` array to be displayed in HTML in a list format, how can I go about doing so?

```
const getData = () => {
  axios
    .get(" https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/charmander")
    .then((response) => {
      const stats = response.data.moves;
      const moves = stats.map((obj) => {
        return obj.move.name;
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a safe helper to populate a node in the page, let's say `<div id="list"></div>`, so that your code can do something like:

```
import {render, html} from '//unpkg.com/uhtml?module';

const getData = () => {
  axios
    .get(" https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/charmander")
    .then((response) => {
      const stats = response.data.moves;
      render(document.getElementById('list'), html`
        <ul>
          ${stats.map((obj) => html`<li>${obj.move.name}</li>`)}
        </ul>
      `);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

That will also do the right thing next time you call `getData` *in case* data changes.

Comment: I am currently using vanilla JS. II am getting this error `TypeError: WeakMap key must be an object, got key` or do I need to add something to my HTML too?

Comment: you need to be sure `document.getElementById('list')` is not `null`

Comment: great works now. I realised I put my id in the wrong HTML element

Comment: I just want to ask one more thing and research bit more. What is the render module that we imported here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition requiring no library (VanillaJS only) :

```js
const getData = () => {
    axios
      .get(" https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/charmander")
      .then((response) => {
        const stats = response.data.moves;
        // Create <ul> tag
        const ul = document.createElement('ul');
        stats.forEach((obj) => {
            // Create <li> tag
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            // Add text to <li>
            li.textContent = obj.move.name;
            // Append <li> to <ul>
            ul.appendChild(li);
        });

        // Append <ul> somewhere in your DOM
        document.getElementById('ul_parent').appendChild('ul');

      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

Comment: I get a `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` error and also the data I get from my API is inside the `return obj.move.name` after I iterate the `stats` variable